# Can't get user status as int

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

ErrorException : Object of class App\People could not be converted to int

```
$check_status = People::select('payment_status')->find($request->people_id);
if ($check_status == 0) {
    return 'active';
}
```

Comment: Try `if ($check_status->payment_status == 0) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, bro that works